# Import error when opening empty notebook

Tags: front-end, windows

When opening notebooks, sometimes, in the messages window I get:

```
During evaluation of In[1]:=
... Import: File not found during Import
```

and also get a second window that only contains `$Failed`

There is nothing wrong with the notebook being opened. I reduced it using a text editor all the way down to:

```
Notebook[{Cell[CellGroupData[{}, Open  ]]}]
```

and I still get the error. I also deleted my Front End init.m with no effect on this. In Mathematica 11, we can do a stack trace on generated errors. By doing so, I got this trace:

```
Message[Import::nffil,Import]
Message[Import::nffil,Import];Throw[$Failed];
ToBoxes[Import[ToFileName[-directlaunch]]]
TimeConstrained[ToBoxes[Import[ToFileName[-directlaunch]]],6.]
TimeConstrained[TimeConstrained[ToBoxes[Import[ToFileName[-directlaunch]]],6.],9.]
```

So my questions are:

- What are steps happen when opening a notebook?
- Is a command like `TimeConstrained[TimeConstrained[ToBoxes[Import[ToFileName[-directlaunch]]],6.],9.]` one of these steps?
- What is it trying to import?

This can probably be solved by resetting all configuration files and deleting all the cache files, but I would like to understand why is this happening.

I am using Mathematica 11.0.1.0 under Windows 7

Comment: the link for the image appears to be broken

Comment: I could not make the image work, so I just replaced it with the text.

Comment: This is a Windows 7 specific issue, likely unrelated to your specific configuration. To fix it, right click on a .nb file, go to "Properties" and ensure "Opens with" is set to the latest version of Mathematica installed on your computer. (I'm on win10 right now so I don't remember the exact dialog, but hopefully this makes sense)

Comment: @user6014 Your solution worked. I also had to restart Mathematica. Before and after the change Mathematica 11 was being launched when I double clicked the notebooks, so I didn't think about that. But in the properties pane, I had version 10.3.1 selected.

Comment: @GustavoDelfino there is something about Windows 7 that doesn't allow you to set any earlier version of Mathematica than the latest that is installed on the machine. Not sure who's at fault. I think if you're really committed you can fix this by adjusting the registry, but I don't know the details.

Comment: @user6014, I've had the same problem, just resolved by your solution. I would suggest that you post it as an answer.

Comment: @user6014, having had this issue again, which your solution resolves, it would be good for this to be an answer so the question is considered answered in the SE system.

Comment: @user6014 could you post your comment as a solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a Windows 7 specific issue, likely unrelated to your specific configuration. To fix it, right click on a .nb file, go to "Properties" and ensure "Opens with" is set to the latest version of Mathematica installed on your computer.