# Problem during opening a second notebook

Tags: evaluation, popup

Suppose I have open a Mathematica notebook and I have evaluated several commands. Then if I try to open a second notebook, while the first is still open the following mesh occurs:

(i) I get the following error message in a pop-up window at the lower left corner "Import::nffil: File not found during Import."
(ii) A new Untitled notebook opens which contains only the following "$Failed".

So what is going on here? I'm running v11.3 in Win 7 64bit. I have to say, that using v9.0 in Win XP I have never experiences this problem.

Any suggestions on how to eliminate this problem?

**EDIT 1:**

A simple test:
Try this: create a notebook "test1.nb" with only the command 2+2 and save it. Then create a second notebook "test2.nb" with the command 3-1 and save it. Now open test1.nb, do not evaluate anything and then, while it is open, open test2.nb. Does it work, or an error message appear?

**EDIT 2:**

This is what I get when I open (without evaluating) a test notebook
[image]

Is the gray "In[]:=" at the upper left corner expected or not?

Comment: Everything opens, there are no problems with Windows 10 and Math 11.3

Comment: @AlexTrounev When you open one of the test files does a gray "In[]:=" appear in front of and above the command?

Comment: No, nothing appears, just open without messages.

Comment: Did you try to [reset Mathematica](http://support.wolfram.com/kb/12464)?

Comment: @AlexTrounev Please see my edit.

Comment: Nothing wrong with your file.

Comment: See https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/140066/import-error-when-opening-empty-notebook - does that help?

Comment: @KraZug Thank you very much! I had both v9.0 and v11.3 installed in my computer. After removing v9.0 all problems disappeared.

Comment: Yes, https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/172069/34161 answers this.

Comment: @Vaggelis_Z, you didn't need to uninstall the older one, just make sure the newer one is the default.